set partitioning formulation for directed vprtw
This assignment is courtesy of Roberto Roberti. The Vehicle Routing Problem with Time Windows (VRPTW) is a generalization of the Capacitated Vehicle Routing Problem (CVRP), where each customer must be visited within a given time window.
The VRPTW can be stated as follows. A directed graph G=(V,A)
is given, where V
is the set of vertices and A
is the set of arcs. The set of vertices V
is defined as V=N∪{o,d}
, where N={1,2,...,n}
is a set of n
customers and o
and d
represent the start and the end point of each route (in practice, o
and d
represent the same depot but are kept separate for notational purposes). The set of arcs A
is defined as A={(i,j):i,j∈V,i≠j}
; a travel cost cij
and a travel time tij
are associated with each arc (i,j)∈A
.
Each customer i∈N
requests qi
units of a given commodity and can be visited only within a given time window [ei,li]
, where ei
and li
are the earliest and the latest time to serve customer i
; nonetheless, a vehicle is allowed to arrive at i
before ei
, but, in this case, the service starts at ei
. A set K={1,2,...,m}
of m
vehicles can be used to serve the customers; each vehicle has capacity Q
.
The goal of the VRPTW is to find a set of routes of minimum total cost to assign to the vehicles, such that
No more than m
routes are selected;
Each route starts from o
within the depot time window, visits a set of customers, each within its time window, whose total requests do not exceed Q
, and ends at d
within the depot time window;
Each customer is visited by exactly one of the routes.
You are given a VRPTW instance in Python code at the end of this document. The layout of the customers is as follows:
It can be helpful adapting the utilities used for the TSP exercises to plot your solutions.
Task 1: Set Partitioning Formulation
Describe how the VRPTW can be formulated as a Set Partitioning (SP) problem.
As usual, to describe a model you have at least to:
introduce the notation
write the full mathematical model
explain every row of the model justifying why it is a correct model of the problem at hand.
An analysis of the model from a computational point of view is a plus.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
